# creating customized application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-activity

i'm new to Java and Android so please don't mind if my question is lacking correct programming terms or is not detail enough!

i'm trying to create an app which will have:

- ActivityArtists - it will contain list of Artist names and their pictures! User will add artists and their pictures on his own! He can add who he wants and as many as he wants!

now comes the part that's causing me problems:

- when he clicks on an artist he previously created i want another activity(ActivityAlbums) to show with another list in which user can add albums and album covers of that artist! things i'm confused about is how can i make (or can i make) something that's still not there start another activity with another layout of his own? please help!
- any link,way,idea or suggestion how i can make something like this is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you plan on storing the information?  Are you going to use a SQLite database?  If you select an artist, you can bundle that artist information to another activity using an intent and pull the album information from the SQLite database.  If there are no albums saved for that artist, raise a toast so the user is aware that no information has been stored yet for that artist.  I can give you an example of some of my code that I use when I pass information from one activity to another.

```
lvProjects.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id){
            Project project = (Project) lvProjects.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Bundle projectBundle = new Bundle();
            projectBundle.putSerializable("project", project);
            Intent evmListIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EVMListActivity.class);
            evmListIntent.putExtras(projectBundle);
            v.getContext().startActivity(evmListIntent);
        }
    });
```

In this code, an item is selected from the listview, bundled, put into an intent, and the next activity is called.  You would then have to get the information out of the bundle in the next activity

```
//get the bundle of project data
    Bundle projectBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    final Project project = (Project) projectBundle.getSerializable("project");
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you recommend using SQLite to store pictures and strings or should i go with some other storage?

Comment: That would depend on how you plan on laying out your tables.  As for images, some quick googling says it's possible, but I don't know how.  You would wind up storing the images on your phone, and that can really start to take up space.  I would recommend SQLite for storing the artist and album information, but I just don't know about the images honestly.  I've never done it.